# NumberFormatException on clicking a button on jsp page

Tags: numberformatexception

I am getting NumberFormatException for the following :

```
 application.setNumOfLicenses(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("appFte")));
```

Here, request.getParameter("appFte") is a blank space. Actually I have a jsp page wherein request.getParameter("appFte") corresponds to the value I input in a text field named as,"No. of Licenses". There's a button called "Create Application on that page. Whenever I click on the button I get NumberFormatException in the console. I want to get rid of it. Can you please suggest me a way to get rid of it. I have even tried using the following :

```
 if(StringUtils.isNumeric(request.getParameter("appFte")))
    {
        application = fillAttributes(application, request);
    }
    else
    {
        error = "Please provide numeric in License No.";
        out.write(error);
    }
```

but still I am getting NumberFormatException in the console. Please help.

Comment: Could you provide value of request.getParameter("appFte")?

Comment: it's a blank space

Comment: Actually I have a jsp page wherein request.getParameter("appFte") corresponds to the value I input in a text field named as,"No. of Licenses". There's a button called "Create Application on that page. Whenever I click on the button I get NumberFormatException in the console. I want to get rid of it. Can you please suggest me a way to get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

You basically answered your question. Parsing empty string causes your exception.

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
        System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(" "));
}

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
```

Make sure that you are converting valid string to Integer like "76".
More info could be found in [Java API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String))

Comment: Actually I have a jsp page wherein request.getParameter("appFte") corresponds to the value I input in a text field named as,"No. of Licenses". There's a button called "Create Application on that page. Whenever I click on the button I get NumberFormatException in the console. I want to get rid of it. Can you please suggest me a way to get rid of it.

Comment: Looks like you have to submit valid parameter. So before clicking button could you set some value in the input like "5" for example.